# Automatic ipv4 interface metrics algorithm?

Tags: ipv4

Here is the link in reference http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299540 
.Is there anything similar for windows 7 ?

Comment: It looks like you can find the same functionality in the Networking \ TCPIP \ [IPv4 Advanced IP Settings Tab](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771274.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It is called routing protocols, you can configure static/dinamic metrics based on path costs, and path weights.... Take a look at here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Shortest_Path_First and here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_Information_Protocol